# Installing ggbiplot package in R

Tags: r

I am currently trying to do a PCA in R and inorder to do that I need to download the ggbiplot package. Eveytime I try to search in the install window it does not show up. I am new to R so any advice or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried downloading by typing download.packages(ggbiplot)into the script window but when I run it I get one of two messages

```
"Error in dir.exists(destdir) : argument "destdir" is missing, with no default"
```

or

```
"Error in install.packages : object 'ggbiplot' not found"
```

Comment: Could you please try running the following code: `library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")` ?

Comment: You should use `install.packages()` rather than `download.packages()` and you need to pass the package name as a string: `install.packages("ggbiplot")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working to revive `ggbiplot` and publish a new version to CRAN.

You can get the current version with

```
remotes::install_github("friendly/ggbiplot")
```